# Serviço não está sendo chamado para fazer update no banco

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, expressões-lambda

Fiz um serviço e quando eu chamo na *URL*, passando os devido parâmetros, não funciona:

Chamada na *URL*:

```
http://localhost:9078/api/atualiza/1000012120/teste
```

Meu serviço:

```
public class AtualizaController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        PedidoLiberacao liberacao = new PedidoLiberacao();

        [AcceptVerbs("Put")]
        public void putItensLiberacao(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
            liberacao.AtualizaLiberacao(id, value);
        }
    }
```

Esse é o método que o serviço chama e faz a atualização no BD:

```
[Route("atualiza/{id}/{value}")]
        public void AtualizaLiberacao(int id, string value)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                        .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id).ToList();

            lista.ForEach(f =>
            {
                f.FlagLiberacao = 0;
                f.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value;
            });

            contexto.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Tá dando **ERRO**:

> page not found(404)

**EDIT2**

O erro acima já não tem mais, mais dá esse erro(Postman):

> {
>       "Message": "O recurso solicitado não suporta o método http 'GET'." }

Assim ficou meu serviço e método

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Atualiza")]
    public class AtualizaController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        PedidoLiberacao liberacao = new PedidoLiberacao();

        [Route("{id}/{value}")]
        [AcceptVerbs("Put")]
        public void putItensLiberacao(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
            liberacao.AtualizaLiberacao(id, value);
        }
    }
```

e o método

```
[Route("atualiza/{id}/{value}")]
        public void AtualizaLiberacao(int id, string value)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                        .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id).ToList();

            lista.ForEach(f =>
            {
                f.FlagLiberacao = 0;
                f.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value;
            });
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
```

No método eu comentei o atributo, mas o erro persiste. Coloquei um break point no serviço e nem sequer entrou.

Comment: Coloque na sua classe Controller (encima da definição) `[RoutePrefix("api/")]` fazendo um favor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acontece que você está usando a definição de rotas por atributos e, desta forma, você precisa definir **a rota completa** do serviço (isso inclui o api/).

Você pode usar o atributo `RoutePrefix` pra não precisar repetir a parte padrão das rotas

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Atualiza")]
public class AtualizaController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{id}/{value}")]
    public void AtualizaLiberacao(int id, string value) { }
}
```

Comment: A lambda está dando pau, o mesmo problema que eu não consegui resolver há tempos, no começo de tudo. Na lambda me dá esse erro:`The 'DataLib' property on 'Liberacao' could not be set to a 'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Single'.`

Comment: @pnet Mas isso não ta ver com o problema da pergunta, né?

Comment: É, tá certo. Vou fazer outro post, caso eu não encontre uma solução. É o hábito.